# Bug in XCode 6 (Beta 3)

Tags: xcode, xcode6

This is about UINavigationItem

There default navigationBar

[image]

As you can see chevron so close to the left side. Why?

If I'll try add

```
var backButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "CUSTOM", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)

newNavigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

I've got

[image]

Comment: Why is that a bug in Xcode?  If it is a bug, it will be in UIKit, won't it?

Comment: Maybe you're right. But if generalize it's problem with XCode 6b3. I mean not in code (Swift) or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was beta 3 bug. New version works perfectly.